# Dismiss an element for x months

Tags: jquery, timer, dismiss

I'd like to dismiss an element (div or class) for a certain amount of time on a site i'm working on. Something like click here to dismiss for 6 months.

I can hide an element via jquery but not sure how to do it for a certain amount of time?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a cookie with the id/class of the div and let it expire after 6 months. jQuery has a usefull cookie plugin:
https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Answer (score 0):

Store it at a database. HTML was designed to have no memory at all, and so, no persistant data. Cookies had to be added by Netscape (and later adopted by every other browser, until it make it on the HTML specs). So, if you don't have a database behind your website, cookies or server-side code (such as storing the date on a text file with PHP) are your only options.